# Tabs not customized as I want in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have the following activity code for a tabbed application.

```
public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabbedactivity);        

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();         

        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("RP");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        photospec.setIndicator("RP", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabrp));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, RP.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MP");
        songspec.setIndicator("MP", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabmp));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, MP.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        tabHost.addTab(photospec);
        tabHost.addTab(songspec);           
    }       
}
```

The tabbedactivity.xml is defined as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I have added tabmp.xml and tabrp.xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

The colors are defined in `color.xml`. The application runs, but the color on the tabs is still the default black when active, gray when not active and blue when pressed, which are the default android colors for tabs. The `tabmp.xml` and `tabrp.xml` does not seen to work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing resource needs to be set as the background of the tab view. You can do one of two things:

1. Once you've created the tab:

   ```
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(THE_CHILDS_POSITION_IN_THE_HOST).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabmp.xml);
   ```
2. Or create a custom layout for your tab

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/tabsLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector"
   android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView android:id="@+id/tabsText" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Title"
           android:textSize="15dp" android:textColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"
           android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   and then when creating your tab:

   ```
   View tabview = LayoutInflator.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
   TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
   tv.setText(TEXT);
   TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(i);
   tabHost.addTab(setContent);
   ```

Comment: I have a layout defined for each of the tabs. i.e. when user clicks on RP, it launches the intent and starts a new activity RP.class and i have rp.xml which loads on its onCreate. I cannot use your 2nd option. As of 1st option, where in the activity posted above would i insert the 1st solution?

Comment: You've got it mixed up. What you've just described is not a layout for a tab but a layout for an activity hosted within a tabwidget. It's not the same thing as a layout being used to describe how the tab indicators will appear. Either solution will work. If you want to use the first solution you would place the code after you call tabhost.addtab(). Josh Clemm has a [pretty darn good explanation on his blog](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Comment: @Intern I'm glad you got it :-)